# MySQL Select Distinct Items and Count at the same time

Tags: mysql

I have a database that looks like this:

```
Dentist | Specialty
Fred       General
Susan      General
Frank      Family
```

I want to select the distinct specialties and also get a count of how many of each specialties there is, this is what I tried:

`SELECT DISTINCT Specialty, COUNT(*) FROM dentists`

However that only returns the first specialty `General` and the count for `General`.  How do I get all of them?

So in the case of the simple database above, I need to know that their is `2 General` and `1 Family`

Comment: I think you're looking for GROUP BY. So "GROUP BY Specialty" then you can drop the 'distinct'

Comment: @chris85 That returns a count of 1 for everything

Comment: I need to count the number of specialties so I need to know there is 2 General and 1 Family

Comment: Ok, it's more important to get the correct counts than to remove specialties with a low amount, i'll get rid of that for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [GROUP BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) command:

`SELECT Specialty, COUNT(*) FROM dentists GROUP BY Specialty`

The `GROUP BY` is telling MySQL to collect all of the similar items together, so you won't need the `DISTINCT` anymore.  As others have suggested, if you want to limit it to Specialties with more than 30 rows, you can then add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 30`, so your final query would be

`SELECT Specialty, COUNT(*) FROM dentists GROUP BY Specialty HAVING COUNT(*) > 30`